# Undefined variable $count in Laravel Blade File

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to send a lot of stats to my dashboard view but I am having undefined variable errors for all the passed variables.
My controller is

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $company_id = $user->company_id;

        $data['emps'] = 600;
        $data['docs'] = 500;

        // $data['users'] = User::where([
        //     'company_id' => $company_id
        // ])->get()->count();

        

        $data['recent_docs'] =[];
        $data['count'] = 1500;
        
        return view('home', $data);
    }
```

In my view I am trying to access the passed values like this

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <x-adminlte-info-box 
                text={{$count}}
                title="Documents"
                theme="gradient-purple"
                icon="fas fa-lg fa-copy text-yellow"
                icon-theme="red"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <x-adminlte-info-box 
                text={{$docs}}
                title="Employees"
                icon="fas fa-lg fa-users text-primary"
                theme="gradient-primary" icon-theme="white"
            />
        </div>
```

Comment: Instead of `text={{$count}}` do `:text="$count"` and also same for `$docs`.

Comment: have you tried `return view('home', compact('data'));`

Comment: @JSTECH sir this is not the issue as hard coded strings are being displayed without any errors. The problem lies somewhere in passing data from controller.

Comment: Then, the error is outside the code that you've provided. Can you give us full controller and/or view or url to repository?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using blade component. In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#passing-data-to-components) there's information that

> You may pass data to Blade components using HTML attributes. Hard-coded, primitive values may be passed to the component using simple HTML attribute strings. PHP expressions and variables should be passed to the component via attributes that use the `:` character as a prefix

So you should use the `$count` in your template like that:

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
    <x-adminlte-info-box 
        :text="$count"
        title="Documents"
        theme="gradient-purple"
        icon="fas fa-lg fa-copy text-yellow"
        icon-theme="red"
    />
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <x-adminlte-info-box 
        :text="$docs"
        title="Employees"
        icon="fas fa-lg fa-users text-primary"
        theme="gradient-primary" icon-theme="white"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Not working gives the same error.

Comment: It is very important to mention that, when I put just strings and do not pass data from controller it works.